# css center div inside div generated by jquery

Tags: jquery, css, overlay, css-position

I'm having problems with a jquery generated div i have. I'm basically trying to make an overlay but only over a specific div.

here's my code:

text... text... and more texts

my jquery:

```
function addOverlay() {
    var overlayExist = $('body').find('#container-that-needs-overlay');

    if (overlayExist.length == 0) {
        var overlay = '<div class="span12" id="overlay" style="margin-left:-20px;">' +
            '<div class="overlay-text-inside-container">This is text I need over the overlay</div>' +
            '<div id="overlay-background"></div>' +
            '</div>';
        jQuery('#form-container').after(overlay);

        var inputContainer = $('#_new-form-input');
        var position = $('#_new-form-input').offset();
        $('#overlay').css({ position: "absolute", left: position.left, top: position.top, width: inputContainer.width() + 20, height: inputContainer.height() });

    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
#overlay-background
{
    background-color: #000;
    filter:alpha(opacity=50);
    -moz-opacity:0.5;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.5;
    opacity: 0.5;
    height:inherit;
    width:inherit;
}

.overlay-text-inside-container
    {
        font-size:large;
        width:50%; 
        height:50%;
        top:50%;
        position: relative;
        text-align:center; /*ultimately centers text*/
        color:White;
    }
```

Now my problem is the overlay gets generated but it would look like this

```
-----------------------div that needs overlay----------------------------------------

 (empty space)
 (empty space) 
 (empty space)
 (empty space)

**************this is where the overlay color starts (id="overlay-background")********
This is text I need over the overlay /////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

-----------------------end of div that needs overlay----------------------------------
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

***************this is where the overlay color ends **********************************
```

Now I'm just trying to figure out how to push that background up the top of the main div. And at the same time center the text vertically and horizontally over the background. Also, the reason why I put in 2 divs is because the text is inheriting the transparency of the background if I placed all the css on the main overlay div. So I thought separating them would do the trick.

Thanks!!

EDIT for Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/6rgMj/

I can't seem to make it pop out with it tho.

UPDATE: Fixed it!

http://jsfiddle.net/6rgMj/2/

Comment: create a fiddle or post html also.

Answer (score 1):

Here you got updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6rgMj/1/

I've add `z-index` property to `.overlay-text-inside-container` and this property bring that element above `#overlay-background`.

I've also change `onclick` attribute in your `a` element, which is a bad habitat. You should try to avoid using JavaScript events in HTML attributes, because this can cause problems with code maintaining in the future.

I'm not sure if this is all you ask, but if not I'll update my answer.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply and for the adjustment of the code. well my main issue is that i need the overlay to cover the whole div, but with the setup that I have it's only covering the bottom half, like what's happening on your edited version. I wanted to have the text inside the overlay to be in the center as well that's why i had the height and width, that kinda messed up the background div as well.